# Changing behaviour of class in c++ via other class

Tags: c++, file, class, reload, friend

We all know that we have *ifstream* and *ofstream* classes with their own functionality: reading, writing, line by line reading etc.

```
ifstream input_file("test.in") ;
ofstream output_file;
output_file.open("test.out");
```

So, let assume now we want to extend reading/writing functional via creating some class (lets call it BackUp) and somehow make *ifstream* and *ofstream* to use BackUp's reading/writing instead (only). As far as I understood this principle is called acquaintance?

The main difference should be that when opening a file a copy of it should be created somewhere. Then we work with this starting file like usually, we overwrite it by our results and if the procedure was successful only then the temporary copy is deleted.

Yes, I know, that it's probadly better just to write and use a common function, but this is not my goal.

I have also made a schemes to understand the logic:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

### Goal

I want the target file to be overwritten if the entire operation is successful, so if the program crashes, if one excidently turns off the PC etc. the data from the original file would be saved atleast somewhere.

### Question itself

I need to grasp the idea itself how this can be done in general case but It would be nice if one would use this particular this example to explain.

Comment: If you want redirect file i/o's check this out http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/

Comment: You would need to create a derived `filebuf` and use it to replace the default stream buffer used by file stream obejcts.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this. If the backup file is deleted after you have finished, why not just write to the target file directly? If you flush the stream all data in its buffer will be forced out to the file.

Comment: Perhaps you only want the target file to be overwritten if the entire operation is successful, so if the program crashes, file will have the original data. But it's not clear to me from your question.

Comment: @Mat the question is how to realise this, how to make a common ifstream and ofstream, when callsing for reading/writing a file to use described functionality, which will be realised in some class BackUp. And even dipper, is there something specific I shell take into account when creating this class?

Comment: @JonathanWakely can you explain more precise? I'm very new to programming.

Comment: nice diagrams, why do you want to be a programmer, you clearly should be a project manager

Comment: @NeilKirk yes, this is the correct explanation WHY I'm doing this all. Sorry for not beeing very clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't decode your sentence. What do you mean by a "functional"? Do you perhaps man "inheritance" instead of "acquaintance"? What is your native language? Maybe you could post what you mean in your language as well, so someone who knows both languages can figure out what you mean? Do you have a friend who could translate your question for you?

Comment: @uliwitness thank you for pointing me on my terms mistake, but unfortuantly I don't know anybody who could help me with the translation (my native languages are Ukrainian and Russian)
By "functional" I mean all functions that are realised in the class.

Comment: @Exceptyon unfortuantly for me the way to project manager lies through programmer

Comment: Write it to your backup file as a normal stream and when you are done, move the file into the final path, overwriting the existing file. You could also accumulate the data in memory, perhaps a string stream or vector, and only output it to the file in one go at the end.

Comment: *moving* the temporary file does the trick. "one go" doesn't help. it's not atomic.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well we have no idea what the requirements are. Strict atomicity may or may not be required.